# How do I close default edit mode of Telerik Radgrid?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, rad

I use Telerik Rad Grid. For the edit one record I add below

```
OnEditCommand="Stackoverflow_EditCommand" and in the grid I wrote
```

---

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CommandArgument="Id">
</telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

From the asp.net page, when I click edit button, there are some default textboxes in order to edit, but I dont want to show them to user, I open a new window and show the textboxes from there. So I dont want to show default edit row, how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is works fine for if you don't want inline editing in radgrid.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn >  
     <ItemTemplate>
       <img src="image/test.png" onclick="OpenPopup('<%#Eval("Id") %>');"/>
      </ItemTemplate>                     
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

now make function like OpenPopup in javascript like this

```
function OpenPopup(id) {

   window.radopen("Popups/Test.aspx?id=" + id, "PopupPage");//here "PopupPage" is id of your rad window
 }
```

now you can get id by Request("id") in test page.

Answer (score 1):

U can change it into Pop-up windows form instead in-Place edit form..
For do that u can click the rad grid, then go to Properties windows, find MasterTableView expand it and find EditMode, change EditMode into PopUp..
Run it, but dont forget to checked Autogenerate edit column at runtime..
hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I do this it is ok. but I dont want to show it. I have a radwindow when I click edit, I want to open it, is it correct to use editcommand or are there any method?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `commandName` to something else than "Edit". For example, use "Change".